# LaTeX help with href

Tags: latex

I am trying to create a hyperlink using LaTeX. When I use the command pdflatex to compile the file, I get an error.

The relevant lines of the document are:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
...
\href{http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html}{gprof}
```

pdflatex created a file called missfont.log, which contains this:

```
mktextfm pzdr
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Do you have the pzdr font installed? If you're on Debian or Ubuntu, try installing the texlive-fonts-recommended package.

Comment: Works for me as well. :)

Answer (score 4):

Does the hyperref package purport to make hyperlinks to arbitrary web pages?  I thought it was just for intra-document links (which it does automatically).  I would do

```
\usepackage{url}
```

and

```
\url{http://foo.com}
```

to format a URL in your document.

ADDED: Thanks Will, I didn't know that about href.  But if you're creating a document that's mainly targeting paper as the intended medium, I think the url package for formatting URLs is the way to go.  But if you think the href package subsumes the url package, I'd love to be set straight on that.